# сортировка колонки с цифрами (sort)

Tags: linux, сортировка

сортирую таблицу в трубе по седьмой колонке с реверсом командой `sort -rgk 7`, и получаю:

```
16.1963
14.5021
2.9748
2.08327
2.12991
1.14502
1.47157
1.50804
```

как задать аргументы чтобы стало правильно по ранжиру в порядке убывания?
надо получить:

```
16.1963
14.5021
2.9748
2.12991
2.08327
1.50804
1.47157
1.14502
```

sort (GNU coreutils) 8.25

Comment: `sort -n` .....

Comment: `-n` тоже не помогает, так же неправильно сортирует после точки в числах, аргумент `-g`вроде как раз и рекомендуется для сортировки подобных чисел вместо `-n`, однако и `-rnk 7` и `-rgk 7` выдают не так, как хочется

Comment: нуда... не заметил `-g` в вопросе.... `-rg` на данной выборке даёт требуемый результат... так что предлагаю дать полные данные... поля точно разделены табами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обновлено:

`awk '{print $7 " " $0;}'| sort -k1,1n | cut -d " " -f 8-`

Распечатает седьмую колонку, в порядке возрастания!

Добавьте `| tac` чтобы реверснуть, и получить вывод 7-ой колонки в порядке убывания!

Comment: я указал, что у меня не файл, а труба, и колонка 7

Comment: tac дает только чтение в обратном порядке, какой от него смысл, если сортирует неправильно

Comment: @Bl0wfish, всё, сделал! Полностью рабочий вариант! Справляется с вашей задачей!

Comment: да, работает, спасибо. Я так и не смог справится с сортировкой по 7й колонке, поскольку мне нужны были все , а не только 7я, я откопировал седьмую в первую и все отсортировалось. Вопрос: можно применить `cut -d " " -f 8-` ко всем колонкам вообще (в том числе если есть колонка без цифр, но чтобы все, которые с фицрами обработало так)?

Comment: Вот это я не знаю пока. Я под скоростью искал решение. Я могу посмотреть, если хотите.